# Mount Ubuntu server directory onto local Ubuntu machine, access via terminal

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, mount, automount

I'm working locally on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine and I often need to access an Ubuntu 12.04 server.  I would like to mount my home drive on the server as a directory on my local machine.  It is important that I can access this directory via terminal.   How can I do this?

Currently I can type `ssh wbp` and access my server.  I can also graphically open *Files* > *Connect to server* and conect via sftp. However… this doesn't seem to mount any kind of directory that I can access via terminal (or my pycharm project browser).

Comment: Try NFS: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-file-system.html

Comment: There's also the inferior [SSHFS](//help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS), if the server doesn't offer NFS or [Samba/CIFS](//wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently).

Comment: There's also [`gvfs-mount(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gvfs-mount.1.html) for SSH/SFTP, FTP, CIFS, and WebDAV, if you don't have local super-user privileges for a regular `mount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the following lines in my .bash_aliases file:

```
alias mountwwbp="sshfs -o nonempty wbp:/home/user /home/user/wbp-home"
alias umountwwbp="fusermount -u /home/user/wbp-home"
```